# Hover to show image or icon in ggplot2 (R markdown)

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I am fascinated by dynamic or interactive ggplot graphs. I found some easy hover options with `ggiraph` at https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/ Here is a MWE for R markdown:

````
---
title: "Hover"
author: "Author"
output: html_document
---
## Hover ggplot2
```{r, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)
data <- mtcars
data$carname <- row.names(data)
gg_point = ggplot(data = data) +
    geom_point_interactive(aes(x = wt, y = qsec, color = disp,
    tooltip = carname, data_id = carname)) +
  theme_minimal()
girafe(ggobj = gg_point)
```
````

[image]

Is there any possibility to show a small image or icon when hover over a datapoint in a ggplot in markdown? I wonder how and where I would store these images. I would like to give every data point a specific image. I am working on famous painters, i.e. assume that I have very few data points in a scatterplot. Thus when people hover on "The Scream", they should see a little version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_expensive_paintings#/media/File:The_Scream_Pastel.jpg

[image]

Comment: [here](https://anchormen.nl/blog/data-science-ai/images-in-plotly-with-r/) is blog that pretty much does what you want, just need to use plotly and a little javascript

Comment: This looks promising, but I can't implement it. I tried to replicate the example with setosa.jpg, virginica.jpg and versicolor.jpg but it's not working. There are no images in my RStudio or RMarkdown.